# Why define C# abstract classes without abstract members

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

am familiar with abstract classes, interfaces, and the like.

What is not clear to me is why anyone would create a C# abstract class that does not have abstract members?
(the C# compiler allows this).

Example:

```
public abstract class House
{
    public void OpenDoor()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Door opens");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think more code would be required in the compiler to spot this "issue" and prevent it. So the question can be reversed - why should the compiler be *specifically* designed to prevent it?

Comment: Indeed a valid question. And in my opinion, this is a sign of bad design. Usually I have done this in my past, and in the end I need to mark `OpenDoor` as virtual because my derived houses need specific method for it. One alternative is to add another method `OnOpenDoor` that is virtual protected, allowing the children to have specific implementation while having control of `absolute` implementation from base class.

Answer (score 4):

You may need a common base to access to refer to so you can process a list of many different types of houses. You could have a `List<House>` and some of those could be `BrickHouse` others `WoodenHouse` but opening the door functions the same for all houses so it makes sense to put the method in the base. You declare the base abstract if it does not make sense to instantiate that class.

Comment: Why not an interface then?

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Can you implement methods in an interface?

Comment: @Heuster No, you can't, as I mentioned in my answer. However, this answer doesn't seem to mention it...

Comment: an interface does not allow you to put any implementation in it, so you wouldn't be able to put the `OpenDoor` method implementation

Comment: @NedStoyanov I know, but you don't mention it in your answer.

Comment: @NedStoyanov What if someday you need to add a `SharedHouse` where the open door implementation can be different? (because the authorization is shared among house but private among rooms)

Comment: @Fendy I think in that case you can declare the `OpenDoor` method virtual and override the implementation for `SharedHouse`

Comment: @NedStoyanov That's exactly my question, why would someone define an abstract class `without` any `virtual / abstract` member?

Answer (score 2):

simply because: you are expected to subclass it?

Maybe in this context, `House` simply isn't specific enough; sure, all things in this relationship are *houses*, but it is expecting concrete types such as `Bungalow`, `Mansion`, `Apartment`, etc... So `House` serves as a useful *categorisation* (for example, in a `List<House>` or a property of type `House`) - but you would never expect to have an actual instance of that common base type.

Comment: If expected to subclass, why not marking it as virtual? Opening door in `Bungalow` can be different from one in `Apartment`.

Comment: @Fendy that depends on the real example - not all methods are best virtual. Some are, some aren't.

Comment: In this case I refering the `OpenDoor` as real example though. And IMHO, abstract class without abstract / virtual member is a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine that some platform (perhaps in a company) might define an abstract class programmers should subclass so that methods can be added in later versions?

Comment: Hmmm... not really, I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

Just to auto implement things for them, so for example provide a default implementation of `GetHashCode`,  or maybe `ToString`. Also, it allows for you to add a method to an interface that the abstract class implements, provide a default implementation, and then nothing breaks, instead of the other option where every class breaks and you have to fix all of them manually.

Comment: Both of `GetHashCode` and `ToString` can be overridden. Why not mark it as virtual?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, `static classes` in C# are in fact `sealed` and `abstract` ones. The purpose in this very case is clear: allowing to declare static methods only.

Comment: While *true*, that doesn't really apply to the (non-`static`) question

Answer (score 0):

*Generalization*

Abstract classes can be a conceptual 'Interface'. This is different from a .NET interface.
A generalized interface example is:

```
// List that accepts the conceptual interface
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

// Specialized instance that will be added to the list
Car myCar = new Toyota();
cars.Add(myCar);
```

*Inheritance*

You can implement multiple interfaces but inherit just from one abstract class. This can be a design decision made by the developer of the class library.

*Usage*

[Dhananjay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10026391/296526) wrote a nice post about the usage. He states that abstract classes are used for modelling your class hierarchy. Interfaces however are used for communication. That the object actually is does not matter.

Comment: Say that I want to has a class named `Fishman`. Is it inherited from `Fish`, or is it inherited from `Mammal`?

Answer (score 0):

So that the base class defines the implementation. If the Implementation is common across all the derived classes it makes sense to keep it in the abstract class not duplicate the code in the derived class.

See this link, has some useful info about this 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6118/All-about-abstract-classes

Answer (score 0):

abstract classes, at all, are more of a logic class to inherit from rather than use it as basic for inheritance, you can use abstract class to tell all who inherits from it to have a certain property or a specific method to do,
Interfaces can do exactly that.

Lets say I have a mammal class, but a mammal class is just an abstract class, there is no real animal that is of a kind of a mammal, although there are many animals ( including humans) that inherit "properties" from it.

Again, abstract use is definitely up for the developer choice.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes with abstract members are meant to be used polymorphically. Abstract classes with only concrete members would be used if you wanted to share common methods with subclasses, perhaps even a specific construction sequence (as in having the abstract class's constructor do setup that's "housekeeping").

It's a weaker form of coupling than polymorphic subclasses, and I can't think of a time I've run across it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class serves as a template (may or may not provide default implementations) while child could overwrite anything he does not like, or additional methods/properties/etc.

a very interesting scenario is type constraint inheritance:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("blah blah");
    }
}

public class MyClass<T>: MyClass
{
    public T GetSomething()
    {
        // return null as T;
    }
}
```

you may see the default implementation is at the base class.

Comment: This is indeed a common pattern for lists of `MyClass` objects because the generic classes otherwise have no shared base class that can be used (except object).

Answer (score 0):

Often the base class is used to provide just common functionality. Depending on your design this common functionality can be implemented without dependencies on members. In this case usually the subclasses don't need any common members. In you example the `House` class of objects is used for simple actions and I assume you don't need any common state of the house such as number of floors, type of walls (wood, bricks, etc.). Seeing such a class makes me think "OK, this class isn't holding any state of the object. It just performs some action"